# Calculate certificate hash

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need to calculate hash of certificate in SHA256 algorithm and provide it to security service. Which certificate format I should use - PEM or DER? Is there any openssl command that calculates certificate hash in standard way?

Comment: You **seriously** need to read and learn more about certificates if you plan to write your own library to do this (which you shouldn't, as everything is out there doing that already) because it is obvious that the fingerprint can't depend on the PEM representation of a certificate as it is an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Either PEM and DER are fine, you can do the following:

`openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -fingerprint -sha256`

Reference:

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html

Comment: I'm planning to write my own programm that calculates hash. And I will get different hashes if I pass certificate as array of bytes in DER and PEM format

Comment: @vico "I'm planning to write my own programm that calculates hash." Why? Also your question asks about `openssl` so this reply answers it even if it makes your question offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: (but you should of course use OpenSSL 3.x and not the old 1.1.1 even if for that specific need it won't change the results)